# How can i go about making a button state active when entry fields are filled?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have my "Create account" button only active if the password field has more than 5 characters.

I have tried to add some if checks to grab the entry field's length. (in code snippet) and my issue with that was the main loop only loops once while the window is open, so I think that wont work.

```py
def createAccount():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('320x125')
    window.title("Create an account")
    window.resizable(False, False)
    window.configure(bg='gray')

    #Buttons
    window.create_close_button = Button(window, text="Close", command=window.destroy)
    create_button = Button(window, text="Create", command=lambda: checkIfValid(
                                            window.create_password_entry,
                                            window.create_confirm_password_entry,
                                            window.create_username_entry,
                                            window), state='disabled')

    #Labels
    window.padding_label = Label(window, bg='gray')
    window.create_username_label = Label(window, text="Username", bg='gray', fg='white')
    window.create_password_label = Label(window, text="Password", bg='gray', fg='white')
    window.create_confirm_password_label = Label(window, text="Confirm Password", bg='gray', fg='white')

    #Entries
    window.create_username_entry = Entry(window, bd=1, bg='gray', fg='white')
    window.create_password_entry = Entry(window, show="*", bd=1, bg='gray', fg='white')
    window.create_confirm_password_entry = Entry(window, show="*", bd=1, bg='gray', fg='white')

    #Add all to grid
    window.create_username_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
    window.create_username_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)
    window.create_password_label.grid(row=2, column=1)
    window.create_password_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)
    window.create_confirm_password_label.grid(row=3, column=1)
    window.create_confirm_password_entry.grid(row=3, column=2)
    window.padding_label.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
    create_button.grid(row=5, column=1)
    window.create_close_button.grid(row=5, column=2)

    def onKey(event):
        if len(window.create_password_entry.get()) < 5:
            create_button.configure(state = 'disabled')
        else:
            create_button.configure(state = 'normal')

    window.create_password_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', onKey)

    window.mainloop()
```

I can't say that I expected the loop to only go through ONE time while the window was open, but I want to see how I could do this in a better way if anyone knows the answer.

---

Error here:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "", line 49, in createAccount
    createAccountMenu.createAccount()
  File "", line 58, in createAccount
    window.bind('<KeyRelease>', onKey)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1251, in bind
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1206, in _bind
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "bind" command: application has been destroyed
```

Comment: everything before `mainloop()` is executed before tkinter shows window - so you if/else check it befoer you even see window. You can to `bind()` event `<Key>` to `Entry` with function which will check length of text in Entry. This function will be executed after every key pressed in `Entry`.

Comment: `bind('<KeyRelease>', onKey)` - without `()` after `onKey`

Comment: `window.create_confirm_password_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', onKey)` instead of `window.bind('<KeyRelease>', onKey)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind event `<KeyRelease>` to `Entry` with function which will check length. This function will be executed every time when you release key in `Entry`

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_key(event):
    #print('len:', len(event.widget.get()))
    #print('len:', len(entry.get()))
    if len(entry.get()) > 5:
        button['state'] = 'normal'
    else:
        button['state'] = 'disabled'

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', on_key)

button = tk.Button(root, text='OK', state='disabled')
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** Code used for test. It works for me without problems. It close correctly.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def createAccount(main_menu_window):

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('320x125')
    window.title("Create an account")
    window.resizable(False, False)
    window.configure(bg='gray')

    #Buttons
    window.create_close_button = Button(window, text="Close", command=window.destroy)
    create_button = Button(window, text="Create", command=lambda: checkIfValid(
                                            window.create_password_entry,
                                            window.create_confirm_password_entry,
                                            window.create_username_entry,
                                            window, main_menu_window), state='disabled')

    #Labels
    window.padding_label = Label(window, bg='gray')
    window.create_username_label = Label(window, text="Username", bg='gray', fg='white')
    window.create_password_label = Label(window, text="Password", bg='gray', fg='white')
    window.create_confirm_password_label = Label(window, text="Confirm Password", bg='gray', fg='white')

    #Entries
    window.create_username_entry = Entry(window, bd=1, bg='gray', fg='white')
    window.create_password_entry = Entry(window, show="*", bd=1, bg='gray', fg='white')
    window.create_confirm_password_entry = Entry(window, show="*", bd=1, bg='gray', fg='white')

    #Add all to grid
    window.create_username_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
    window.create_username_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)
    window.create_password_label.grid(row=2, column=1)
    window.create_password_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)
    window.create_confirm_password_label.grid(row=3, column=1)
    window.create_confirm_password_entry.grid(row=3, column=2)
    window.padding_label.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
    create_button.grid(row=5, column=1)
    window.create_close_button.grid(row=5, column=2)

    def onKey(event):
        if len(window.create_password_entry.get()) < 5:
            create_button['state'] = 'disabled'
        else:
            create_button['state'] = 'normal'

    window.create_password_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', onKey)

    window.mainloop()

def checkIfValid(create_password_entry, create_confirm_password_entry, create_username_entry, window, window_2):
    print(create_password_entry.get())
    print(create_confirm_password_entry.get())
    print(create_username_entry.get())
    window.destroy()
    window_2.destroy()

window = tk.Tk()
Button(window, text='Create Account', command=lambda:createAccount(window)).pack()
Button(window, text='Close', command=window.destroy).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I get an error when I do this. Not a runtime error, but it doesn't seem to work for me, and when I try to close the window out, it gives me an error trying to run that function on other things in the window as well.

Comment: what error ? Text "doesn't work" is the most useless inforamtion.

Comment: Will edit initial post with code breakdown of error

Comment: did you use name of your Entry instead of `entry` ? and `window` instead of `root` ?

Comment: see may code - it has to be name of function without `()` - `bind('<KeyRelease>', onKey)` - it is called "callback". In tkinter you use `callback` (name of function without `()`) in `bind()`, `after()` and `Button( command=...)`

Comment: Yes I used the name of the Tk.Entry instead of the window. Now I am getting a different error. I will update the error field in the main post

Comment: you have to use name of your Entry instead of my `entry`, not `window`. If you bind to `window` then it will try to run function when you press key in any place, not only inside Entry.

Comment: Edited main post to reflect what code I have in place now.

Comment: did you use `bind()` before `mainloop()` like in my code ? I can get `can't invoke "bind" command: application has been destroyed` only if I use `bind()` after `mainloop()` which is incorrect.

Comment: everything after `mainloop()` is executed after you close window - so `bind` after `mainloop` tries to bind to window which doesn't exists any more.

Comment: BTW: you don't have `window.create_button` but `create_button` so use `create_button['state'] = 'disabled'` instead of `window.create_button['state'] = 'disabled'`

Comment: Ah it worked. That was my issue. I have another issue now though, when i close out that menu, and go back to the main menu, i have to click close twice to get it to close. Without the code i only have to click once. Is there some process i need to kill when the create_window is destroyed?

Comment: another mistake - you forgot `event` in `def onKey(event)`

Comment: Ah yeah I added that in after I moved the mainloop() call.

Comment: it should close normally. I don't see code which could make problem. I create main window with only two buttons to test your code and it closes without problems.

Comment: For some reason closing the create_account GUI, returning back to the main_menu GUI, I have to press close twice. I should note that when I initially got those errors, they only happened when I went back to the main menu and tried to close the main menu out. I think it has to do with where that function is.

Comment: now I see what you mean. You would have to send main window as argument to `create_account` and use `destroy()` on both windows.

Comment: I appreciate all your help!

Comment: I changed code so it closes both windows when you use button `Create` but go back to main menu when you use button `Close` in `createAccount`. If you want close both window even when you use `Close` then you could destroy first window before you create new window `main_menu_window.destroy()`, `window = tk.Tk()`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `trace_add` callback set for an `event` on the entry field variable.

The following example activates the button when text is added to the entry, and disables it when the entry is cleared.

```
import tkinter as tk

def toggle_button(txt_var):
    if txt_var.get():
        btn.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
    else:
        btn.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

root = tk.Tk()

txt = tk.StringVar(root)
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=txt)
entry.pack()

btn = tk.Button(root, text='button', command=lambda: print('this'), state=tk.DISABLED)
btn.pack()

txt.trace_add('write', lambda v_name, ndx, mode, txt_var=txt: toggle_button(txt_var))

root.mainloop()
```